# morgan logger not writing to file

Tags: node.js, logging, morgan

I am trying to set up a production logging environment in my express nodejs application using morgan.

I tried to do it using this documentation https://github.com/expressjs/morgan#write-logs-to-a-file

My code regarding the logging looks like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var logger = require('morgan');
var FileStreamRotator = require('file-stream-rotator');
var fs = require('fs');
var app = express();

// logging
if (app.get('env') !== 'development') {
  var logDirectory = path.join('/srv/iss', 'log');

  // ensure log directory exists
  fs.existsSync(logDirectory) || fs.mkdirSync(logDirectory);

  var accessLogStream = FileStreamRotator.getStream({
    date_format: 'YYYYMMDD',
    filename: path.join(logDirectory, 'access-%DATE%.log'),
    frequency: 'daily',
    verbose: false
  });

  // setup the logger
  app.use(logger('combined', {stream: accessLogStream}))
}
else {
  app.use(logger('dev'));
}
```

When I start the application in development mode everything works fine, but in production mode the access log file is created, but no log messages are sent into the file.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem and just solved.
Just because the read-me is to old to use.
try this:

```
app.use({format:'default', stream: accessLogStream});
```